# bundle format is ambiguous (could be app or framework) while making Archive

Tags: ios, swift, ios-frameworks

I have integrated [this OAuth Library](https://github.com/p2/OAuth2#git) I have followed the Installation instruction, App builds fine in developing mode, while making archive I am getting this,

```
CodeSign /Users/shujaathaider/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jamesAppV2-hhfnrydqoghbzpgsvepxtuzarqrc/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Home\ Automation\ Sys\ Swift/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/OAuth2.framework
    cd "/Users/shujaathaider/Desktop/Workspace_qadir/JamesApp - Development/OAuth2-master"
    export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"

Signing Identity:     "iPhone Developer: Ghulam Hemani (HB4LLMX2DD)"

    /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign C72D0E8EEBE104D1EA0AA0D15558EF38808250F3 /Users/shujaathaider/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jamesAppV2-hhfnrydqoghbzpgsvepxtuzarqrc/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Home\ Automation\ Sys\ Swift/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/OAuth2.framework

/Users/shujaathaider/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jamesAppV2-hhfnrydqoghbzpgsvepxtuzarqrc/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Home Automation Sys Swift/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/OAuth2.framework: bundle format is ambiguous (could be app or framework)
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

Here is how I have integrated the library:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are integrating both the OS X **and** iOS versions of the framework into the app. You only need the iOS version, so remove `OAuth2 (OAuth2)` from *Target Dependencies* and remove `OAuth.framework ...in build/Debug` from *Copy Frameworks*.

Comment: I solved the issue. you were too late. I suffered alot.

Comment: I get the same swiftc error, I don't have target dependencies or frameworks apart from the iOS items